# I'm new to Angular js, I want to display the local JSON data in the HTML file. Below is the code I tried

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a sample JSON file `text.json`. I would like to display the data in HTML using `ng-repeat` but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
    <head>
        <title> Test</title>
        <script src="js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
            myapp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
                $http.get("js/text.json").success(function (response) {
                    $scope.names = response;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <li ng-repeat="value in names">
                {{value.name +' and the age is ' + value.age}}
            </li>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Change `{{value.name +' and the age is ' + value.age}}` to 

`{{value.name}} and the age is {{value.age}}`

Comment: <li ng-repeat="...">{{value.name}} and the age is {{value.age}}</li>

Comment: No Luck.. below is the JSON code..

[{'name':'test', 'age':28},
  {'name':'test1', 'age':28},
  {'name':'test2', 'age':28},
  {'name':'test4', 'age':28},
  {'name':'test3', 'age':28},
]

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Are you getting the wrong data? Are you getting any data at all? Can you add a `console.log(response)` on the line where you get the response, and tell us what it prints?

Comment: I think there is some trivial error - invalid JSON file or a wrong path to the file. Or maybe absence of web server - it won't work through a `file` protocol.

Comment: JS: Use `.then` instead of `.success`. And in HTML: `{{value.name}}' and the age is {{value.age}}`

Comment: @Aniket Sinha `.success()` is absolutely a proper way how to get a data through `$http` service. If he used `.then()` function he would also needed change `$scope.names = response;` to `$scope.names = response.data;`.

Comment: Surya once simply inside your  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">{{8*9}}
</div> give like this and check the anjularjs is wrking in it

Comment: Thank you.. The JSON path is not correct.. Its working fine now...

Comment: @Surya No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: @Surya: if your problem resolve , accept answer and up vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Idea 1**

Maybe the JSON file is invalid. Edit it by removing the last comma into this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "test",
    "age": 28
  },
  {
    "name": "test1",
    "age": 28
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "age": 28
  },
  {
    "name": "test4",
    "age": 28
  },
  {
    "name": "test3",
    "age": 28
  }
]
```

**Idea 2**

Double check the path to the JSON file. Is `js/text.json` really the correct one?

**Idea 3**

Do you use some web server to display your file in a browser? It probably won't work through a file protocol (e.g. `file:///myfile.html`), you need a web server and http protocol (e.g. `http://localhost:9000`).

**Idea 4**

If you are using some historical version of AngularJS baybe there is a problem with interpolation.

`{{}}` is a marker for AngularJS interpolation - it means you can display any value which does exist in Angular's scope. You are creating one by `ng-repeat`.
Compared to that, "and the age is" is a simple text which doesn't need an interpolation (it is not variable on Angular's scope but a simple constant).

It means you need to interpolate only `{{value.name}}` and `{{value.age}}`. It should work with this code:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <li ng-repeat="value in names">
      {{value.name}} and the age is {{value.age}}
   </li>
</div>
```

Comment: He might not *need* to interpolate the whole thing, but if `$scope.names` is what he's assuming it to be, the code he posted should still work.

Comment: No Luck.. below is the JSON code.. [{'name':'test', 'age':28}, {'name':'test1', 'age':28}, {'name':'test2', 'age':28}, {'name':'test4', 'age':28}, {'name':'test3', 'age':28}, ]

Comment: @Fissio It depends on Angular version but you are right, it is very unlikely he is using a historical one.

Answer (score -1):

Change to this "{{value.name}} and the age is {{value.age}}" Only if the json data is correct.

Please separate the 'controller' and 'app.js' files so that easily identify the issue.

```
    return $http
                                        .get(
                                                'http://localhost:8089/eCommerce/product/attributes/'
                                                        )
                                        .then(
                                                function(response) {

                                                    return response.data;
                                                },
                                                function(errResponse) {
                                                    console
                                                            .error('Error while fetching specific Item');
                                                    return $q
                                                            .reject(errResponse);
                                                });
                            }
```